# Tensorflow dtypes in typing hints

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-typing

Is it possible to specify a tensor’s dtype in the typing hint of a function? We use `input_signature` to declare the signature of a `tf.function`, why is not as simple to declare the dtype of a tensor. Having `tf.Tensor` as a hint is not always enough.